# How to get enum value;

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enums:

**Days:**

```
Sunday    1
Monday    2
Tuesday   4
Wednesday 8
Thursday  16
Friday    32
Saturday  64
```

**WeekOfMonth**

```
First     256
Second    512
Third     1024
Fourth    2048
```

I have, for example, the number 514 which is a sum of 512(`Second`) +2(`Monday`).

How can I get Second & Monday if I only have the number 514?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need an enumeration there? Seems like there is either a sequence or a logic involved, perhaps you can write some code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a logical AND against each possible value. All values that return non zero are the ones that you want.

```
var finalValue = ... // 512 -> 1000000010
var possibleValues = ... // array of flags [00000001, 000000010, 00000100, 00001000 ... ]

var appliedFlags = possibleValues.Where(x => x & finalValue == x).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the accepting the answer. Personally I like  @Martin's answer more. I just wish I had thought of that :P

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the following definitions:

```
[Flags]
enum Days {
  Sunday = 1,
  Monday = 2,
  Tuesday = 4,
  Wednesday = 8,
  Thursday = 16,
  Friday = 32,
  Saturday = 64
}

[Flags]
enum WeekOfMonth {
  First = 256,
  Second = 512,
  Third = 1024,
  Fourth = 2048
}
```

You can get the desired string using this code:

```
var value = (Int32) WeekOfMonth.Second + (Int32) Days.Monday; // 514
var days = (Days) (value & 0xFF);
var weekOfMonth = (WeekOfMonth) (value & 0xFF00);
var str = String.Format("{0} & {1}", weekOfMonth, days);
```

The variable `str` will contain `Second & Monday` as desired.

The `[Flags]` attribute is important if you want to be able to combine several `Days` values or `WeekOfMonth` values. For instance `((Days) 3).ToString()` will return `Sunday, Monday`. If you forget the `[Flags]` attribute the string returned is `3`.

Comment: Gah - I was just typing that! +1 ;-)

Comment: Well, in my code i have added the [Flags], Just forgot to post it. :(

Answer (score 0):

well I have an idea as I can see it seems to be binary sequence , so you can subtract this number 514 to the nearest binary which will be 512 then do the same process to the remaining until you got 0.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work:
Take the number and divide it by the int value of the first WeekOfMonth value. The result will be a double, ignore everthing behind the comma. Now you have the value for WeekOfMonth.
Afterwards use mod (%) division to get the rest of the division to get the remaining value which represtns your Days value.

In code:

```
var intValue = (int)WeekOfMonth.Second + (int)Days.Monday; //514
var weekOfMonth = (WeekOfMonth)Convert.ToInt32(intValue / (int)WeekOfMonth.First);
var day = (Days)(intValue % (int)WeekOfMonth.First);
```

I'm not sure if all the casts are working but it should give you the idea ;)